# 'dpinst /silent' fails on Windows XP with signed (but not WHQL) drivers

Tags: windows, driver-signing, dpinst

[Driver Package Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544842%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (DPInst) with the ["/s"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544775%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (silent) flag fails to install a signed driver on Windows XP. The certificate is a valid one (an [Authenticode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing#Implementations) certificate) but not a [WHQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHQL_Testing) one. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: FI: installer log information ("high level") [is in *%SystemRoot%\DPINST.LOG*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544842%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (typically *C:\WINDOWS\DPINST.LOG*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DPInst has two "silencing" flags -- `/q` (Quiet) and `/sw` (Supress Wizard). `/q` implies Quiet but also probably (I didn't test!) sets DI_QUIETINSTALL when issuing the DIF_REMOVE request. Apparently this makes the SetupAPI library (of Windows XP) go "they're trying to go sneaky on me!" and reject the installation if the certificate isn't a treasured WHQL[*] one.

Note that DPInst itself ignores the certificate's validity when the `/lm` (Legacy Mode) flag is set, but it's the underlying Windows that'll reject it still.

The solution is to use the `/sw` flag (along with `/lm`).

*BTW, I'm still yet to check the implications of this - e.g. does Windows pop-up a "STOP Installation" prompt box under some configurations? I'll test and update this answer accordingly.*

#### The "STOP Installation" prompt" looks like:

[image: Sole window displayed under some circumstances for commandline flag "/sq /lm"]

[*] ... or another Windows System Component Verification certificate, but that's besides the point.

Comment: What came out of the tests?

Comment: IIRC, it does NOT pop-up the "STOP installation" prompt. Windows is offended by the "keep quiet" flag and rejects unsigned drivers, but if you don't actually ask it to be quiet (/sw only silences DpInst), it doesn't actually say anything. Quite passive aggressive if I may say.

Answer (score 0):

If the device driver is signed, you need to add its publisher to trusted publisher list.
follow steps mentioned in below article

http://www.richud.com/wiki/Windows_7_Broken_Trusted_Publisher_Certificates_signed_Drivers_fix

after this silent installation will work fine.

Comment: Well, yes, marking "Always trust software from ..." in DpInst does exactly that -- adds it to the Trusted Publishers in the certificate store. My question was completely different -- about the difference between /sw (Supress Wizard) and /silent. The dialog in the article comes from DpInst itself, not from SetupAPI.